# How Can I create Blue View in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'd like to create a View with a pure background color of blue in SwiftUI.

What I'm going to do, in UIKit I'm going to create a UIView. But SwiftUI doesn't have UIView in it

just look like this。 NO have text， NO have Image。
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is seems simplest (if you need to have it explicitly named)

[image]

```
struct BlueView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Or just use `Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` in-place (like background, etc.)